# Woher kommt "suutsche"?

Tags: etymology, regional, slang

Folgenden Dialog könnte man in weiten Teilen Norddeutschlands hören:

> *"Ab an die Arbeit, Männer! Pause is' vorbei!"*
>
> *"Immer **suutsche**, Chef. Geht gleich los."*

"Immer suutsche" (oder schreibt man es "sutsche"?) steht hier für "immer mit der Ruhe", "mach mal langsam", "keinen Streß" oder "locker bleiben".

Aber wo kommt es her, und was bedeutet es im eigentlichen Wortsinn?

Comment: wird übrigens sutsche oder sutje geschrieben, vom plattdeutschen suutje

Comment: Der Duden kennt übrigens [sutje](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sutje)

Answer (score 5):

"[Suutsche](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sutsche)" bedeutet "sachte", "locker", "entspannt" und kommt aus dem (oh Wunder!) Plattdeutschen. Dort heißt es "suutje".

Answer (score 3):

Das "sch" in der genannten Schreibweise kommt daher, dass das "j" in [niederdeutschen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niederdeutsche_Sprache) Wörtern in manchen Gegenden tatsächlich wie ein weiches "sch" ausgesprochen wird. Das ist aber wohl nicht die "korrekte" Schreibweise. Das wäre "sutje".